# What is the correct term for the columns in a number system?

Tags: number-systems

In the base 10 number system you have units, tens, hundreds etc...

These can be represented as columns such as:

### | 1000 | 100  | 10 | u |

What is the correct mathematical term for these columns?

Comment: The term you're probably looking for is "place values."

Comment: Thanks symplectomorphic, but wouldn't that apply more to the values in the columns? What about the column headers themselves - for example is there a word that would describe "100" in this context?